# Mocking instance creation in Groovy with Powermock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mockito, testng, powermock

I'm trying to mock instance creation via new operator in Groovy class with Powermock (1.7.0RC2), Mockito2 (2.4.0) and TestNG (6.8.21). But usual approach is not working. Here are my classes and test.

```
public class A {
    public String send() {
        B b = new B();
        return b.send();
    }
}    

public class B {       
    public String send() {
        return "SendFromOriginB";
    }
}

@PrepareForTest([A.class])
class TestConstructor extends PowerMockTestCase {
    @Mock
    private B bMock

    @Test
    void test() {
      A a = new A()

     given(bMock.send()).willReturn("Send from B mock")
     PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(bMock)
     assertEquals(a.send(), "Send from B mock")
    }
}
```

The problem is that A class is a **Groovy class**. And it seems that **Powermock.whenNew** doesn't know that **new B()** is calling.

So, **var b** contains **usual instance** of B class rather than **mock** and test fails. But, if A class is a **Java class** then test works as I expected and **var b** contains my **mock**. Groovy creates instance by its own means and I can't mock them correctly.

Does anyone have any idea how to mock instance creation in Groovy class?

Comment: could you provide full runnable script with `@Gape()` and `imports`?

Comment: @alex-voronkov did you ever figure out how to mock instance creation of Groovy class? I am having same issue

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand that Groovy is not Java? What makes you think that constructs that work for the Java language work for *other* languages?

In that sense: your first step should be to use [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) to *inspect* the **class** file created by Groovy for class A. See what is in there.

Beyond that: replacing `new` with a **factory** and allowing to *inject* that factory would allow you to test this easily, you would not even need PowerMock then.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions!

Use [@CompileStatic](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/CompileStatic.html):

```
@CompileStatic // <- you can use on class level
public class A {

    // Or you can use on method level 
    // depending on groovy version
    @CompileStatic
    public String send() {
        // 
    }
}
```

This annotation will remove the metaprogramming protocol that breaks the PowerMock.whenNew() method.

My second suggestion is to use [Spock Framework](http://spockframework.org/)! This frameworks is based on BDD and make your test code very clean and readable when you are using groovy! Spock can [mock constructor](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#MockingConstructors) too.

Your test code in spock could be something like this:

```
def "Given an class A, when B constructor returns a mock, a must use the mock"() {
    given:
    String sendFromBMock = "Send from B mock"
    and:
    bMock.send() >> sendFromBMock
    when:
    new B() >> bMock
    then:
    a.send() == sendFromBMock
}
```